# Mail Chimp Input Vs Button Dilemma → Button not working, but Input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Here is the Mailchimp shortcode used in the Wordpress:
Here is the code →

```
<div class="email-button-one-line">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email-<?php echo $random?>" value="" class="field-email-oneline" placeholder="<?php _e('Your Email Address', 'charito');?>"/><input type="submit" class="button field-email-button" name="mailchimp_submit" id="mailchimp_submit-<?php echo $random?>" value="<?php _e("Subscribe", 'charito');?>" />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                jQuery('#mailchimp_submit-<?php echo $random?>').click(function()
                {
                    jQuery('#process-<?php echo $random?>').css('display','block');
                    var datastring = '&name=' + escape(jQuery('#name-<?php echo $random?>').val()) + '&email=' + escape(jQuery('#email-<?php echo $random?>').val()) + '&api_key=<?php echo get_theme_mod('blogeto_mailchimp_api_key');?>&list_id=<?php echo get_theme_mod('blogeto_mailchimp_list_id');?>';
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo rest_url('/mc/rest/pchimp/');?>',
                        data: datastring,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            jQuery('#process-<?php echo $random?>').css('display','none');
                            jQuery('#newsletter_msg-<?php echo $random?>').html(msg);
                        },
                        error: function(msg)
                        {
                            jQuery('#process-<?php echo $random?>').css('display','none');
                            jQuery('#newsletter_msg-<?php echo $random?>').html(msg);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
        });
    </script>
```

## Issue→

This code portion is an issue to be discussed:

```
<input type="submit" class="button field-email-button" name="mailchimp_submit" id="mailchimp_submit-<?php echo $random?>" value="<?php _e("Subscribe", 'charito');?>" />
```

I wish to change this to button, but as soon as I do this →

```
<button type="submit" class="button field-email-button" name="mailchimp_submit" id="mailchimp_submit-<?php echo $random?>" value="<?php _e("Subscribe", 'charito');?>" />  <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Subscribe   </button>
```

It stops working.

> You might argue why button?

## Reason →

1. there are various other options such as Aweber, Feedburner etc; in
   total 7 and the CSS IS wrote in such a way to use the `button`
2. secondly, I have to also use this : `<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Subscribe` which is not possible in `<input>`

when I change the `input` to `button` why it doesn't work, and what is the fix?